# Are Bitcoin in Thailand illegal?

Tags: legal

I have read conflicting reports on whether Thailand declared Bitcoin illegal or not. What has happened and how did it affect Bitcoin commerce in Thailand?

To what degree are there restrictions? I.e. which out of the common actions (possession, personal transactions, mining, private trading and commercial trading) with bitcoin are illegal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://bitcoin.co.th/trading-suspended-due-to-bank-of-thailand-advisement/

The short version of that article direct from Bitcoin is...

Do not send/receive/mine Bitcoin if you are in Thailand.  Do not buy/sell to any one where the receiving/sending wallet is in Thailand and/or the product (virtual or real) is sent via Thailand.  Currency laws have not caught up to virtual currencies and how ( if it can be done ) it can be taxed. Bitcoin, as a group, has decided it is in the best interest of the virtual currency to try and stop trades to/from that country and ask people there to not mine ( it is really hard to stop someone from logging in to a pool and mining if they want to )

Bitcoin Co. Ltd. has currency exchange applications currently pending review with the Bank of Thailand